# Hibernate Search , changes the default Analyzer

Tags: full-text-search, hibernate-search

I want to utilize a custom Analyzer like default. Searching online on the Hibernate search ' s documentation, i saw that is possibile changing it in the Hibernate configuration. In particular with the property "hibernate.search.analyzer". Then I made this property

```
<property name="hibernate.search.analyzer">Class of Analyzer </property>
```

My question is: How I can create a analyzer' s class for pass it  at the property?
In particolary I want use the "EdgeNGram" , I tried to pass the EngedNgram' s tokenizer factory , but it not works .

```
<property name="hibernate.search.analyzer">EdgeNGramTokenizerFactory.class</property>
```

Can you show me a Example of the class that I can pass at this property ? Thanks

Answer (score 5):

EDIT: Hibernate Search 6+ users, what follows is mostly irrelevant to you. Read [this section of the documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/search/reference/en-US/html_single/#getting-started-analysis) instead.

First, let me warn you that the default analyzer should generally be a general-purpose one, one that may not be great, but is good enough for most fields. As new requirements are added to your application, you are very unlikely to be able to use the same analyzer everywhere, and will ultimately have to use specific analyzers in at least some of your index fields. That's why I personally prefer to use `org.apache.lucene.analysis.core.KeywordAnalyzer` as a default, and specify an analyzer wherever I need one.

EDIT: With Hibernate Search 6 this advice (using a keyword analyzer by default) has become less relevant, since [keyword fields](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/search/reference/en-US/html_single/#mapper-orm-directfieldmapping-annotations-keywordfield) and [full-text fields](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/search/reference/en-US/html_single/#mapper-orm-directfieldmapping-annotations-fulltextfield) are clearly separated. Still, that's good advice for Hibernate Search 5.

Now, you've been warned: using an `EdgeNGramTokenizerFactory` for your default analyzer is probably a bad idea. If you still want to do it, read on...

The default analyzer doesn't have to be a class. It can be the fully qualified name of a class, but here you want a custom analyzer, and writing your own analyzer class can be complex, so if you're not used to Lucene I wouldn't recommend it.

What you can do instead is use the name of a [named analyzer](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/search/5.10/reference/en-US/html_single/#section-named-analyzers) defined using [an `@AnalyzerDef` annotation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/search/5.10/reference/en-US/html_single/#_analyzer_definition_through_annotations) or [an analysis definition provider](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/search/5.10/reference/en-US/html_single/#section-programmatic-analyzer-definition). These definitions use "off the shelf" analysis components and assemble them to a fully-fledged analyzer, which is much easier to do.

So, for example, you can define this class, which is not an analyzer class, but rather a class that provides analyzer definitions:

```
package com.acme.search;

import org.apache.lucene.analysis.core.ASCIIFoldingFilterFactory;
import org.apache.lucene.analysis.core.LowerCaseFilterFactory;
import org.apache.lucene.analysis.ngram.EdgeNGramTokenizerFactory;
import org.hibernate.search.analyzer.definition.LuceneAnalysisDefinitionProvider;
import org.hibernate.search.analyzer.definition.LuceneAnalysisDefinitionRegistryBuilder;

public class CustomAnalyzerProvider implements LuceneAnalysisDefinitionProvider {
    @Override
    public void register(LuceneAnalyzerDefinitionRegistryBuilder builder) {
        builder
                .analyzer( "myAnalyzer" )
                        .tokenizer( EdgeNGramTokenizerFactory.class )
                                .param( "minGramSize" "1" )
                                .param( "maxGramSize", "5" )
                        .tokenFilter( ASCIIFoldingFilterFactory.class )
                        .tokenFilter( LowerCaseFilterFactory.class );
    }
}
```

Then define the following properties in your `persistence.xml`:

```
<property name="hibernate.search.lucene.analysis_definition_provider">com.acme.search.CustomAnalyzerProvider</property>
<property name="hibernate.search.analyzer">myAnalyzer</property>
```

And you should be good to go.

**EDIT**: If you use the Elasticsearch integration, then 1) using a custom Lucene Analyzer class **will never work** and 2) you need to do this to defined named analyzers instead:

Define this class, which is not an analyzer class, but rather a class that provides analyzer definitions:

```
package com.acme.search;

import org.hibernate.search.elasticsearch.analyzer.definition.ElasticsearchAnalysisDefinitionProvider;
import org.hibernate.search.elasticsearch.analyzer.definition.ElasticsearchAnalysisDefinitionRegistryBuilder;

public class CustomAnalyzerProvider implements ElasticsearchAnalysisDefinitionProvider {
    @Override
    public void register(initionRegistryBuilder builder) {
        builder.analyzer( "myAnalyzer" )
                .withTokenizer( "myEdgeNgram" )
                .withCharFilters( "asciifolding" )
                .withTokenFilters( "lowercase" );

        builder.tokenizer( "myEdgeNgram" )
                .type( "edge_ngram" )
                .param( "min_gram", "1" )
                .param( "max_gram", "5" );
    }
}
```

Then define the following properties in your `persistence.xml` (**note the properties are different from my example with Lucene**):

```
<property name="hibernate.search.elasticsearch.analysis_definition_provider">com.acme.search.CustomAnalyzerProvider</property>
<property name="hibernate.search.analyzer">myAnalyzer</property>
```

I you need more information, [the documentation might help](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/search/5.10/reference/en-US/html_single/#elasticsearch-mapping-analyzer).

Comment: I don't have a persistence.xml but a hibernate.xfg.xml. Now i Tried with this class.    class EdgeNGramAnalyzer extends Analyzer{

 @Override
 protected TokenStreamComponents createComponents(String arg0) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub

  NGramTokenizer NG = new NGramTokenizer ();
  TokenStream tok = new StandardFilter(NG);
        // make everything lowercase, remove if not needed
        tok = new LowerCaseFilter(tok);
        //provide stopwords if you want them
        //tok = new StopFilter(tok," ");
  return new TokenStreamComponents(NG, tok);
 }

} Can it works?

Comment: In any case both my class and yours do not work. On this project there is also an integration of Elasticsearch and I see that the indexes do not have the new Analyzer. If I make a partial search query there is no match with anything. There are no exceptions at startup, but it simply does not work.

Comment: @ChristianScarselli I edited my answer to address the case of the Elasticsearch integration.